# Play a file located on a remote laptop, in that machine itself from distant machine

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, hdmi, music

I have two Linux machines. The first is an old laptop that has an ubuntu 18.04 server and serves mainly as a storage device over a home network(as well as an experimental machine); the second machine is also a laptop with Pop_os on it.

I am using the server as a container of music files. The server laptop is backstage and is connecting to the TV via HDMI, and since it has no working keyboard nor screen, all the interaction is made through an ssh connection.

My question is how can I play the files on the server(so that they go right to TV speakers) be played on the server itself, controlled by the ssh connection to that server?

I hope it makes sense. I have installed cmus(command line player) on the server machine.

Thank you.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control a emus instance on a box remotely via the CLI then you can use cmus-remote.

Demonstration and explanation on this YouTube link:-

https://youtu.be/fWL0bjCau68